# CSS making two divs equal height with display table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

In the following HTML, the div .left and .right have different heights. Is it possible to make both `divs` same height without defining the height. I have tried using `display:table` but does not work.

```css
 .wrap{
        overflow:hidden;
        width:250px;
        display: table;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    
    .left{
        width:100px;
        float:left;
        display: table-cell;
        border-bottom:1px solid green;    
    }
    
    
    .right{
        width:150px;
        float:left;
        border-bottom:1px solid red;
        display: table-cell;     
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrap">
    
        <div class="left">
           Lorem    
        </div>
    
        <div class="right">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>
    
    </div>
```

**jsfiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/fJbTX/1/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Remove the `float`, which takes the elements out of the document's normal flow, and also add in another wrapper element, to act as the `table-row`:

> `table-cell`, behaves like the `<td>`  HTML element

Which implies that this requires (though I've not verified my inference) a `display: table-row` parent, as a `td` requires a `tr` parent-element.

```
.wrap{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:250px;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.left{
    width: 50%;
    display: table-cell; 
    background-color: #0f0;
}


.right{
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #f00;
    display: table-cell;     
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fJbTX/4/).

References:

- [CSS display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS:display).

Comment: You don't need a div with `display: table-row`, the browser will add it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179502/is-it-valid-to-use-css-table-cell-with-no-table-row

Comment: If float is being added by somewhere else in your stylesheet. You may add to your .left and .rigth divs `float:none` property to cancel the effect of that float.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/fJbTX/3/

I took out the float property

Comment: Removing float fixed it for me.  Funny thing is that I had to reload the page for the change to take effect, using Firebug to remove float didn't cause the "cells" to become the same height.