# Aligining divs side by side with no gap css

Tags: css

I have divs align side by side generated from a loop,

But there are gap between the 1st and 4th div , how can i remove that gap? Please help..

The image of my div is here [image]

I have added the css as

```
.div_class {
    bottom: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
    height: auto !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/en8F9/)

Comment: use jquery masonry plugin to achieve this

Comment: If you can show your problem in a fiddle that will be more helpful

Comment: try resetting `margin:0, padding: 0`

Comment: Can you mark this gap on the picture? I'm not sure what we're talking about

Comment: try isotope layouts.. hope it helps... http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Possible duplicat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586277/css-making-two-divs-equal-height-with-display-table

Comment: @Rex: I have added one fiddle.. thanks ..Please see the edited question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this jQuery plugins:

[masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)
[isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

These plugins do this besides.