# Bootstrap 3 - make div inside column same height as the other columns on the same row.

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

As per the title, I've tried with making `height:100%` `min-height:100%` etc but it's not helping.

The following from similar questions make all columns into equal heights but I need the inside div stretch 100% to match the height of the other columns on the same row.

```
[class*="col-"]{
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
        background-color: red;
}
.row {
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Other columns contain images with `img-responsive` class so they resize automatically by the viewport size and this div in question will have mix of text and image.

Here is [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/4z3PE/1/)

Comment: Are you using the compiled CSS or are you creating your CSS with LESS? I have an equalheights script for Bootstrap but it only works if you change the less files on the mixins.less and grid.less, it does't affect any performance but it requires that position:relative be moved to the min-width of each col- breakpoint and some other stuff. Do you mean to use this on xs columns? it will be very tiny.

Comment: The problem is because column elements are given `float:left` style. You can't do height calculations in pure CSS with floated elements.

Comment: given you are using bs3 and considering the targeted browsers I would use css display table on the container element and display table-cell for the inner elements. check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586277/css-making-two-divs-equal-height-with-display-table

Comment: With js on document ready or resize ? http://jsfiddle.net/4z3PE/2/d

Answer (score 4):

Yo may use  `table-row` and `table-cell` for display, but you have to disable the floating style for each `col` element,

```
.row {
    display: table-row;
}

[class*="col-"]{
    background-color: red;

    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davc6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap @kariem's CSS in `@media` directives to allow for dynamically stacking columns:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .row {
        display: table-row;
    }

    [class*="col-"]{
        float: none;
        display: table-cell;
    }
}
```

Just be sure to use the appropriate `min-width` and column sizes (`col-lg-`, `col-md-`, etc).
http://jsfiddle.net/davc6/23/