# Is it valid to use css table-cell with no table-row?

Tags: html, css, semantics

I'm working on a layout and I need the behaviour of table-cells but I don't want to use the html `table` element. This is my html and css :

**HTML**

```
<div class="l-tr">
    <div class="l-td">
        <p>....</p>
    </div>
    <div class="l-td">
        <p>....</p>
    </div>
    <div class="l-td">
        <p>....</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.l-tr{
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.l-td{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

My question is: **Is this valid html/css?** Do I need a `div` with `display: table-row`?

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/49W5A/43/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: CSS has nothing to do with HTML, the way is written is valid and the way you use it is coherent. If an extra wrapper as table-row is needed , the browser will do it himself, like it always insert a tbody in a table when you do not :). Your HTML is valid too by itself :). W3C has online validator, you can use them

Comment: @cimmanon your answer on the other question is very informative, thanks for sharing :)