# How to set my divB height equal to another divC which both inside a same divA

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
#divA {
  width:100%;
  border: 2px red solid;
}

#divB {
  border: 2px blue solid;
  width:68%;
  float:left;

}

#divC {
  border: 2px green solid;
  width:28%;
  height:80px; 
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="divA">
      <div id="divB"></div>
      <div id="divC"></div>
    </div>
```

I may input some data from ajax and put into divC so the height of divC is dynamic and I want to set my height of divB is equal to divC when divC's height is change.

How to set my divB height equal to another divC which both inside a same divA?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS making two divs equal height with display table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586277/css-making-two-divs-equal-height-with-display-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st Option: Flexbox**

Flexbox can do that with a single property added to  the parent

```
#divA {
  width:100%;
  border: 2px red solid;
  display:flex;
}
```

Spacing can be achieved by adding `justify-content:space-between` to the parent also.

[**Support**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) is IE10 & up

```css
#divA {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px red solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
#divB {
  border: 2px blue solid;
  width: 68%;
  float: left;
}
#divC {
  border: 2px green solid;
  width: 28%;
  height: 80px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="divA">
  <div id="divB"></div>
  <div id="divC"></div>
</div>
```

**2nd Option: CSS Tables**

```css
#divA {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px red solid;
  display: table;
}
#divB {
  border: 2px blue solid;
  width: 68%;
  display: table-cell;
}
#divC {
  border: 2px green solid;
  width: 28%;
  height: 80px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="divA">
  <div id="divB"></div>
  <div id="divC"></div>
</div>
```

**Caveat:** As you can see you lose control of the spacing here although it's a small price to pay for increased browser [**Support**](http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20table) which is IE8+

Comment: Don't forget to put disclaimer about browser support of `flex`.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can do it as simple as this:

```js
$('#divB').height( $('#divC').height() );
```

```css
#divA {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px red solid;
}

#divB {
  border: 2px blue solid;
  width: 68%;
  float: left;
}

#divC {
  border: 2px green solid;
  width: 28%;
  height: 80px; 
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divA">
  <div id="divB"></div>
  <div id="divC"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript Solution**

In your ajax call back set divB height equal to divC after appending data to divC.

Something Like this:

```
$.ajax({
      url:"your uel",  
      success:function(data) {
       $('#divC').html( data );
       //OR may be append
        //$('#divC').append( data );
        newHeight = $('#divC').height();
        $('#divB').height( newHeight );
      }
   });
```