# CSS: How to properly use display=flex?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

So I'm using Bootstrap's grid system and I found an issue where the columns have different heights depending the content. I've search the net and came across using flex.

It seems to work very well. The issue I'm having is that when I'm testing the page on my desktop by reducing the browser width, it will misaligned suddenly (see screenshots below).

I also tested on an iPhone and the display is messed up on portrait. It's fine on landscape. No problem at all on iPads since I guess it's not hitting the required width for the issues to appear.

Any ideas on how to fix?

---

**my css** (The odd/even classes is to just striped the rows so it's easier to see)

```
div.table {
    margin: 0;
}

div.table-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.table div {
    padding: 12px;
}

div.table-flex [class*="col-"] {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

div.table div.odd {
    background-color: rgb(216, 216, 216);
    border: 1px solid white;
}

div.table div.even {
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

**my html**

```
<div class="row table table-flex">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 odd">Mr First Last</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 even">12345</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 odd">CEO</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 even">Acme Corporation</div>
</div>
```

**grid still displaying ok** (at this point, Firefox inspector says the width is around 510px)
[image: grid still displaying ok]

**from the display ok above, I reduced the browser width a bit and it turned to this** (the weird part is that I was expecting Firefox inspector to say the width is smaller since I was reducing the browser width but it expanded to 542)
[image: from the display ok above, I reduced the width a bit and it turned to this]

Comment: Can you add a snippet pls...

Comment: It's hard to help without a working snippet. Can you add a minimal, working snippet?

Comment: can you please tell in both images what is the screen size ?

Comment: use table setup. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586277/css-making-two-divs-equal-height-with-display-table

Comment: u want all tabs in one line ha?after resize of the browser also all 4  columns should be displayed in the same line ???

Comment: if u want all columns in same line add    div.table-flex {
    display: flex;
    width
    :100%
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

Comment: it would be nice to know if this fixed your question and select it as the answer or not let us know what we did wrong , we invest our time into answering these

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a direct answer since nothing is provided to us , but your flex element might be growing since the browser configures as the width is increasing . Try adding

```
  flex-grow :0
```

This property tells the flex not to grow if there is enough space for it to grow. By default it is 1. Although this will prevent it from growing for larger browser sizes as well if u want it to increase this might not be your choise. Do give it a try and let me know . I will update my answer once you provide any snippets

UPDATED ANSWER -

I manged to fix your issue but im not sure how far this is what you want. The issue lies with the

```
div.table-flex 
{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;

} .
```

Theres two of almost identical elements in your CSS file and im not sure why but they seem to confuse the browser. Once i added the flex-direction and flex-grow properties to it it worked. Do take a look at let me know .

```
div.table 
{
margin: 0;
}

div.table-flex 
{
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: column;
flex-grow: 0;
}

div.table div 
{
padding: 12px;
}

div.table-flex [class*="col-"] 
{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-grow: 0;
}

div.table div.odd 
{
background-color: rgb(216, 216, 216);
border: 1px solid white;
}

div.table div.even {
background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Take a look at this fiddle . https://jsfiddle.net/zrvx06yw/